# Poisson Distribution for X > y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm curious if there is a faster method for solving the following problem:

Michael is observing the occurrence of bicycle accidents, and he has determined that B = the number of accidents in one day has a Poisson distribution with parameter 2.1.

a) What is the probability that there will be 21 or more accidents in one week?

To solve this problem, I would need:
$P(X >= 21) = 1 - P(X < 21) = 1 - P(20) - ... - P(1).$

Additionally, I think you must convert $\lambda = 2.1 $ into a lambda that is relevant to the accidents per week instead of day. The above calculation takes a lot of plugging into the formula:
$f(x) =  \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$

Is there a quicker method to do this problem?

Comment: You could get a bound with the [Markov Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To convert and use the right $\lambda$ you must assume the probability of accidents is independent. That said: you should look for what is the distribution of a sum of independent Poisson random variables.
2. As for doing the sum fast, I suggest you to use a computer algebra system (Mathematica, Maple, etc...). There is no easy "trick".

Comment: I was thinking maybe there was another trick instead of calculating the sums. Would the CDF be a good choice here? Although if I had this question on the exam I'd probably just do the 20 sums quickly instead of risking it with integration.

Comment: The Poisson is a discrete random variable, its CDF is given by a sum and  **not** an integral.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that

$P(X=n+1)=\lambda/(n+1)*P(X=n)$